# Whats wrong with this short procedure (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, function, session, procedure

Im trying to make a procedure, which will be checking if user is already logged (he got a session, and im checking if his last action was over 15 minutes ago). My procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `isLogged`(in p_sessid VARCHAR(32), out res INT(1))
BEGIN
   DECLARE v_customer_id INT(9);
   DECLARE v_date DATE;

   SELECT customer_id INTO v_customer_id FROM Sessions WHERE sessid=p_sessid;
   SELECT expiry_date INTO v_date FROM Sessions WHERE sessid=p_sessid;

   SET res=3;

   IF v_customer_id > 0 THEN 
      IF UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(v_date) THEN
         DELETE FROM Sessions WHERE sessid=p_sessid;
         SET res=1;
     ELSE
         UPDATE Sessions SET expiry_date=DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE) WHERE customer_id=v_customer_id;
         SET res=0;
      END IF;
   END IF;
END
```

Can anyone tell, why it always return 1, what means that user is not logged anymore? I were checking manually expression UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(v_date), and it gives me 0 in response, so? Whats going on?

Thanks in advance,
Marcin

Comment: In my opinion, everything is ok, but it doesnt work. I need to find any debugger, where i can put expression, breakpoint, and check step by step, what values are in variables.

Comment: Have you seen debugger link in my answer?

Answer (score 2):

The first IF statement should read like this:

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(v_date, INTERVAL 15 MINUTE))
```

or else NOW will always be greater than the last login date.

Comment: When im setting date, im always put there now() + 15 minutes, so its not true.

Answer (score 0):

You may rewrite/optimize your procedure to function. For example -

```
CREATE FUNCTION `isLogged`(IN p_sessid VARCHAR(32))
  RETURNS INT
BEGIN

  DELETE FROM Sessions WHERE sessid = p_sessid AND v_date <= NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE;
  IF ROW_COUNT() > 0 THEN -- check how many rows were deleted
    RETURN 1;
  ELSE
    UPDATE Sessions SET expiry_date = NOW() + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE WHERE customer_id = v_customer_id;
    IF ROW_COUNT() > 0 THEN -- check how many rows were updated
      RETURN 0;
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN 3;
END
```

Also, you can try to [debug](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/code-debugger.html) your code to understand the error.

Comment: You set expiry date for NOW() + 15 minutes, and you check if expiry date is lower than NOW() - 15 minutes. Its not good. Lets say, its 7:00. You check, if you are logged. Its true, and expiry date is set for 7:15. Then, after 5 minutes, you perform action, and your script check if 7:15 lower than 7:05 - 15 minutes -> if 7:15 < 6:55. Bad logic. It could be lower after 30 minues or more.

Comment: I did not suggest you a logic with time difference. I suggested you another logic to skip first SELECT statements.

Answer (score 0):

Omg, that was very stupid.

There was a type mismatch. v_date type was a DATE, and this is just a day! Like 2011-12-14.

**Solution:**

change DATE -> DATETIME.

And now everything works good.
Anyway, thank you for answers.